# How to store image as URL in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel

In my application I add photos that are then scaled, I call them to my views using `{{asset()}}`

Everything works fine, but for my mobile app I need to send to API URL of image instead of just image path called from db.

**That's how I save images now:**

```
        $image = $request->photo_patch;
        $filename = time() . '.' . $image->extension();
        $event->photo_patch = $filename;
        $image_resize = Image::make($image->getRealPath());
        $image_resize->resize(1200, 630);
        $image_resize->save('storage/images/' . ($filename));

        $event->save();
```

**Example of saved image name:**

```
1630531230.jpg
```

**That's how I get image on view:**

```
<img src="{{ asset('storage/images/' . $eventView->photo_patch) }}">
```

**What I tried:**

```
$url = Storage::url($filename);
        $event->photo_patch = $url;
```

After this file name looks like this

```
"/storage/1631043493.png"
```

But that isnt really URL

**What can I do to save photo path like this:**

```
"localhost/storage/images/1631043493.png"
```

Edit:
@ Фарид Ахмедов suggested to call whole URL in API.

How can I do that then?

This is what I tried:

```
Route::get('/events/{id}', function($id){

    return [
    Event::findOrFail($id),
    'image' => asset('storage/images/'.$this->photo_patch)
    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it.

```php
url(Storage::url($filename));
```

But I think, you don't need to save the whole path. You can convert it to full URL before sending response.

Comment: So I would stick to code that i've got now and then in API I can convert it to full URL? How can I do that then?

Comment: Hmm... where you have a controller and a method that returns a URL, make a modification there. I didn't quite understand the question.

Comment: Line of code you added is the same that I did. But I was thinking about giving to api 'image' as URL (editied question, its at the bottom of it)

Comment: But this is all that is needed. `asset` helper already returns full URL, that you can use in mobile app as a link. If I understand correctly, you want to send an image, not a link. Then use `return response->file($path)`, that return Blob (binary format), and you can render image on client side.

Comment: I don't see a problem

Comment: Attached updated code is not correct, btw. `$this` is not defined